# how do i register a combo of keys to play sound

Tags: c#, winforms

i am in the process of making a soundboard app (windows forms) and i want to play selected sound on for example, LeftAlt+a keys pressed
tried:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread TH = new Thread(KeyboardPlay);
     TH.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     TH.Start();
}

void KeyboardPlay()
{
      while (IsRunning)
      {

          Thread.Sleep(40);
          if ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.LeftAlt&Key.A) & KeyStates.Down) > 0)
          {

              Console.WriteLine("LeftAlt pressed");
          }
      } 
}
```

I have also tried with `KeyEventArgs` and it didn't seem to work for me

help would be nice :)

Comment: Do speak about a combobox? Or on what control do you want to act? The form itself and any control?

Comment: i want to act on these commands:                                                                                                                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.SoundLocation = openfiledialog1.filename;
                player.Load();
                player.Play();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a control, you can react on KeyUp or KeyDown event:

```
private void Control_Key/*UpOrDown*/(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if ( e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.A )
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

On the form including any control:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
  if ( keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.A) )
  {
    // ...
    return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it more logical to put this on a KeyDown event? Like this, it would only trigger when you _release_ the combination.

Comment: @Nyerguds No, it is a UX anti-pattern to use KeyDown because it is too brutal: it prevents the user from changing his mind. It is like using MouseDown on a control to trigger an action... you click on a button, you change your mind, mouve the mouse and release the button outside the button but it launch the action... damn! Use MouseClick ou MouseUp. Down is to do others things like preparing ou changing UI like cursor or color or anything else that is not THE action itself.

Comment: @OlivierRogier If you press delete in your file system, you will get your "are you sure?" box at the moment you start holding down the key, not when you release it. Likewise, when you paste something, anywhere, it will happen at the moment you push both Ctrl and V, not when you release it. All shortcuts systems work that way. It is what users are used to. Hold down [Ctrl] in your browser and then hold down 'O'. You'll see. It'll respond even if you don't release the combination. It is not an "anti-pattern'. It is the norm. Buttons to click simply don't work the same way as keys.

Comment: Also do note, the question is about a soundboard app. This would be like a piano that only plays a sound at the moment you release a key, rather than at the moment you actually push it down. Not to mention, unlike with buttons to click, there is no way to "cancel" the action anyway; any key you press you will eventually be released and trigger the `KeyUp` anyway.